# How to fix Rest API error in WordPress 5.5?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, rest

I've just updated to WordPress 5.5 and got error below with debug Mode.

```
rest_validate_value_from_schema was called incorrectly. The "type" schema keyword for [0] can only be one of the built-in types: array, object, string, number, integer, boolean, and null. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.
```

I'm using custom end point to create some custom blocks.

```
function example_custom_route()
{
register_rest_route('example/v1', 'posts', [
    'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'example_result_posts',
    'permission_callback' => function () {
        return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
    }
]);
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'example_custom_route');

function example_result_posts()
{
    $posts_result = [];
    $post_type = 'post';

    $posts = get_posts([
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ]);
    if (!empty($posts)) {
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            array_push($posts_result, [
                'value' => $post->ID,
                'label' => wp_specialchars_decode(wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_title)),
            ]);
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return $posts_result;
}
```

What is 'The "type" schema keyword' and how can I fix it?

Still searching for the solition for this... on 14th aug.

Comment: The error is being generated at [wp-includes/rest-api.php line 1582](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_validate_value_from_schema/). If you put a breakpoint here you can then examine the stack of calls to get an idea of where the issue is arising. Sorry, I can't be of more help without knowing what your custom code looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP 5.5 [started throwing notices when `rest_validate_value_from_schema()` is called without required parameters, or with incorrect values](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48821). The allowed values for a `type` property are `'array', 'object', 'string', 'number', 'integer', 'boolean', 'null'`.

The code you shared doesn't produce any errors for me, so it may be that the problem is in some of the code that you didn't share? If you're registering a block with attributes, then [each attribute will need a `type` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-attributes/).

*Aside: There's [a dedicated WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). You'll probably get better responses there in the future.*

Comment: I found a spelling mistake in the attributes. 'Interger' ->'integer'.
I'm so embarrassed..
After fixing this, the error message disappeared.
Thank you so much for your help and kind advice for the next question :)

Comment: , yeah, I do that myself at least once a week

Comment: I had a similar problem. An unwanted space in 'string '. I was getting nothing between "for" and "can".  I raised a TRAC ticket to correct the doing_it_wrong message so that it told you which field was in error. See WordPress TRAC #51231. Of couse, the message would be more helpful if it reported the incorrect value as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try this - Deactivate all the plugins and refresh and see if it works. If yes, then install plugins one by one and refresh after every plugin installation. If you find the plugin that's causing the issue, delete that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not using any plugins and if I remove my custom blocks, the error message disappears.